# Get all the following siblings of an element in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a use-case when the first `.my-class` should be in one state, and all the rest siblings `.my-class` should be in another, so I need to make a few assertions on the **first** and a few others on the rest.

Here is my **first** access:

```js
cy.get('.custom-expand').first().should('have.class', 'custom-expand-expanded')
```

How can I assert the rest `should('not.have.class'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the rest elements by the [`nextAll`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/nextall) function:

```js
cy.get('.cx-custom-expand').first().should('have.class', 'cx-custom-expand-expanded')
cy.get('.cx-custom-expand').first().nextAll().should('not.have.class', 'cx-custom-expand-expanded')
```

Or even:

```js
const first = cy.get('.cx-custom-expand').first()
const rest = first.nextAll()

// do you tests on them
first.should('have.class', 'cx-custom-expand-expanded')
rest.should('not.have.class', 'cx-custom-expand-expanded')
```

Comment: This answer is completely useless. The question is about skipping the first item and taking the rest of the items. While, the `nextAll`  gets siblings of the already selected elements. [Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/nextall).

Comment: @manymanymore "make a few assertions on the first and a few others on the rest", so, it's OK to select the first element first.

Comment: You are wrong. You clearly do not understand the question. The `nextAll` works with siblings, but not filters away the first sequence element.

Comment: @manymanymore Thanks, I added "siblings" to the question.

Comment: Could you update the question title to something like `Get all the following siblings of an element in Cypress`, please?